# Disable a jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins, destroy

I'm writing a script, and I'd like to be able to disable a jQuery plugin when some arbitrary event fires.

Specifically, the plugin offers a page flipping functionality that makes a set of divs appear as pages in a book, and I want to be able to disable the entire plugin during some unimportant event to offer another view at a user's discretion.

The plugin is executed like this:

```
$("#bookDiv").booklet( some options here);
```

Any ideas on how to do this? I've searched stackoverflow and google for a bit and have found nothing, so any help would be appreciated...

Comment: This will depend strongly on what `booklet()` does exactly to the DOM elements it affects. If the plugin doesn't offer this functionality itself, you may have to delve into the plugin's source code

Comment: Can you provide a link to the plugin's documentation?

Comment: Sure, good idea:
http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/